# AngularJS Access DOM inside $watch function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, watch

I'm making a directive that resizes a div based on changes in the controller. I need to calculate the amount of available space left in the browser window when changes happen to the model. How do you pass in the element from the link function into the $watch function?

In short, how do I manipulate the DOM based on changes to the model?

```
    var module = angular.module('cmsApp')
      module.directive("changeWidth", function($timeout) {
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
             width = element.width();
             $scope.$watch('currentFolder', function(value){
                // manipulate dom  here
              });

          }
        }
      });


      <!-- need to calculate the size of this -->
      <div change-width class="col-md-9 right-pannel"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly but you should be able to reference your element argument inside the $watch function already. What is not working?

Comment: No. I can't access anything outside of the watch function.

Comment: where is `currentFolder` defined? plus, can you create a [live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/) illustrating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Angular is even executing your directive based on your template code. It should be

```
<div change-width class="col-md-9 right-pannel"></div>
```

I know this is a source of errors if you are new to Angular. From the docs:

> Angular uses name-with-dashes for its custom attributes and camelCase
>   for the corresponding directives which implement them)

Comment: I fixed that, but the directive still has the same problem. Thanks.